# Removes a key at a given index r and its associated value from this symbol table

Tags: java, data-structures, symbol-table

I need help understanding how to go about this... I need to remove the key at index r and its associated value from this list. Anything that would point me towards the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Inside the function I have written what I thought would help but its not really helping me

```
public class SortedArrayST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {
    private static final int MIN_SIZE = 2;
    private Key[] keys;      // the keys array
    private Value[] vals;    // the values array
    private int N = 0;       // size of the symbol table

    public SortedArrayST(int size) {
        keys = (Key[])(new Comparable[size]);
        vals = (Value[])(new Object[size]);
    }

    public int size() {
        return N;
    } 

    private void remove(int r) {
        if (keys == null) return;
        for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++){
            // iterate through the list
            // if key is at index r and if key is at associated value
            // remove from list
        }
}
```

Comment: can't you just use a map instead of the two arrays?

Comment: the point of this assignment is to use two arrays :/ I wish we can use map lol

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways. One is to shift the array values along, starting at the index you want to remove, then set the last item to Null and decrease N.

Also, bare in mind you're not setting N in your constructor.

Comment: can you please help me start that?

Comment: NVM, I have figured it out! What you said what sufficent, THANK YOU :D